# how to repeat the same future function each time another function is called?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

**i am trying to display a typing indicator before showing a message, i have tried the code below but it only displays the typing indicator once (only for the first message), what i want is to display it each time i want to print a message.**

**this is after modification, the code still after the first message does not display the typing indicator again**

```
import 'package:bubble/bubble.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_chat_bubble/bubble_type.dart';
import 'package:flutter_chat_bubble/chat_bubble.dart';
import 'package:flutter_chat_bubble/clippers/chat_bubble_clipper_2.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dialogflow/dialogflow_v2.dart';
import 'package:progress_indicators/progress_indicators.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Bot());
}

class Bot extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'bot',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(title: 'bot'),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool _nextWidget = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void myMethod(){
    Future.delayed(
        const Duration(
          seconds: 5,
          milliseconds: 500,
        ),
            () {
          if (this.mounted) {
            setState(() {
              _nextWidget = true;
            });
          }
        });
  }
  void response(query) async {
    AuthGoogle authGoogle = await AuthGoogle(
        fileJson: "assets/credentials.json").build();
    Dialogflow dialogflow =
    Dialogflow(authGoogle: authGoogle, language: Language.english);
    AIResponse aiResponse = await dialogflow.detectIntent(query);
    setState(() {
      messsages.insert(0, {
        "data": 0,
        "message": aiResponse.getListMessage()[0]["text"]["text"][0].toString()
      });
    });
    print(aiResponse.getListMessage()[0]["text"]["text"][0].toString());
  }
  final messageInsert = TextEditingController();
  List<Map> messsages = List();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor:  Colors.grey[850],
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white, size: 45)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  reverse: true,
                  itemCount: messsages.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => chat(
                      messsages[index]["message"].toString(),
                      messsages[index]["data"])
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey[850],
              child: ListTile(
                leading: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.mic_off, color: Colors.white, size: 35),
                ),
                title: Container(
                  height: 45,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    cursorColor: Colors.grey[850],
                    controller: messageInsert,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Chat with me",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black
                      ),
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Colors.black
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {}
                  )
                ),
                trailing:
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.send,
                      size: 30.0,
                      color: Colors.greenAccent,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (messageInsert.text.isEmpty) {
                        print("empty message");
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          messsages.insert(0,
                              {"data": 1, "message": messageInsert.text});
                        });
                        response(messageInsert.text);
                        messageInsert.clear();
                      }
                      FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
                      if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                        currentFocus.unfocus();
                      }
                    })
              )
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0)
          ]
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  Widget bot(String message) {
    myMethod();
    return _nextWidget ?  botMessage(message) : botInd();
  }

  Widget botInd() {
    return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
        child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 75, maxHeight: 100),
            child: JumpingDotsProgressIndicator(fontSize: 50.0, color: Colors.white)
        )
    );
  }

  Widget botMessage(String message) {
    return ChatBubble(
        clipper: ChatBubbleClipper2(type: BubbleType.receiverBubble),
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
        backGroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7),
            child: Text(
                message,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
            )
        )
    );
  }

  Widget user(String message) {
    return ChatBubble(
        clipper: ChatBubbleClipper2(type: BubbleType.sendBubble),
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
        backGroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7),
            child: Text(
                message,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
            )
        )
    );
  }

  Widget chat(String message, int data) {
    return data == 0 ? bot(message) : user(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: it is because init state runs only once for any state object

Comment: how can i fix that so it can run multiple times ?

Answer (score 0):

The initState method runs 1 time just before your code appears on the screen. Therefore, I suggest you use the block of code you wrote in the initState method and want to run, by creating a new method other than initState like:

```
void myMethod(){

  Future.delayed(
    const Duration(
      seconds: 7,
      milliseconds: 500,
    ),
        () {
      if (this.mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _nextWidget = !_nextWidget;
    });
  }
});}
```

After doing that, try calling "myMethod".

Hope this works for you.

Comment: it did not work the method kept on repeating, so the output kept on switching between the indicator and the message

Comment: You created a new method like i said but you still have these codes in your initState, when you create the method that called "myMethod", you need to delete these codes inside of your initState. Cause you will use the new created method where you want to use

Comment: And you created the method like i said but you never call that method anywhere, can you try to call that method when you want to execute

Comment: i tried to do that but still not working it keeps on repeating itself, instead of stopping when the message is displayed.

Comment: I think the problem is, you make _nextWidget variable true in your "myMethod" method but you never make false again and each 5.5 secs botMessage is returning:

`Widget bot(String message) {
    myMethod();
    return _nextWidget ?  botMessage(message) : botInd();
  }`

you return botMessage if _nextWidget is true. When you execute "myMethod" you made it true but you are not turn it false again.

Comment: where should i turn it false again

Comment: Try to turn it false after 500 milliseconds delayed under the _nextWidget turns true in "myMethod"

Comment: it did not work, it kept on repeating itself every 500 milliseconds

Comment: Can you try this:

`Widget bot(String message) async {
    await myMethod();
    return _nextWidget ?  botMessage(message) : botInd();
_nextWidget = false;
  }`

Comment: and remove the 500 milliseconds that i just tell you to add

Comment: the following error occurs "type 'Future<Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'"

Comment: and the _nextWidget = false is automatically commented after the return statement

Comment: Oh ok so can you try this:
`Future<Widget> bot(String message) async {     await myMethod();     return _nextWidget ?  botMessage(message) : botInd();   }`

after add this code try to made _nexWidget false after where you call "botMessage" method and "botInd"

Comment: the following error occurs "type 'Future<Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'"

Comment: Can you look at that for "type 'Future<Widget>' is not .... error:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27582#issuecomment-461097939